# Python file output

Tags: python, output, text-files

Method should receive input and output file as arguments.
Convert the text to upper case
Remove all the following characters from the file: %.,-();'0123456789-—:`’
Create a list called “values” that contains the contents of the file broken apart on 
spaces.
Call frequency Table passing “values” and the output file

```
f = open('source.txt', 'r')
fo = open('outputsource.txt','w')

Characters = ("%.,-();'0123456789-—:`’")

def processFile(f,fo):

f.close()
fo.close()
```

I'm having trouble even being able to write the original file back into the output. Very lost on this, been trying to find examples that will help me but I have not been able to. Would love some help on this, as i'm trying to learn it, I'm just very confused. I have had more than what is on screen, but none of it worked like I wanted and now I just need some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is the documentation for file reading and writing.

Comment: Read the tutorial here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files Use 'with open' syntax. Read line by line, modify the line as you need, save the words in a list, and then write to a file. You can use split and re.sub to break on words and remove unwanted characters. Give that a try and then ask where you need help.